# ASP tag "orientation"

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have the following labels and textboxes -

```
<div>

 <fieldset class="myform">
   <legend>Form</legend>

   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="fname">First Name:</asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="lname">Last Name:</asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="lname" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

   <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="town">Address1:</asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

   <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="town">Town:</asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="town" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

  </fieldset>

 </div>
```

The output is that the labels -(fname,lname,address etc) are nicely lined up and textboxes are not, what I am trying to do is so the text boxes are lined up?

any help much appreciated, thanks

so I want like this

```
 First Name  [          ]
  Last Name  [          ]
    Address  [          ]
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

use your styling.

in your css type

```
.textEntry {left:20px;}
```

20 is random number; you can adjust as per your needs.This will cause all your textboxes to align at a particular distance from the left

Answer (score 0):

You add a class to your code `labels`

```
  <div>

 <fieldset class="myform">
 <legend>Form</legend>

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="labels" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="fname">First   Name:</asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

 <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="labels" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="lname">Last Name:</asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="lname" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

 <asp:Label ID="Label3" class="labels" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="town">Address1:</asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

 <asp:Label ID="Label5" class="labels" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="town">Town:     </asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="town" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox> <br>

</fieldset>

</div>​​​
```

Then your css could be this.

```
.myform {text-align:right;width:300px; }
.labels {padding-right:10px;}
```